# Standard Error of variance component from the output of lmer

Tags: r, lme4

I need to extract the `standard error` of variance component from the output of `lmer` .

```
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

The following produces estimates of variance component :

```
s2 <- VarCorr(model)$Subject[1]
```

It is **NOT** the standard error of the variance. And I want the standard error . How can I have it ?

#### EDIT :

Perhaps I am unable to make you understand what I meant by "standard error of the variance component". So I am editing my post .

In Chapter 12 , Experiments with Random Factors , of the book [Design and Analysis of Experiments](http://www.abebooks.com/Design-Analysis-Experiments-5th-Edition-Douglas/9011127330/bd) , by Douglas C. Montgomery , at the end of the chapter , Example 12-2 is done by SAS . In Example 12-2 , the model is a two-factor factorial random effect model .The output is given in Table 12-17

[image]

I am trying to fit the model in R by `lmer` .

```
library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(y~(1|operator)+(1|part),data=dat)
```

R codes for extracting the `Estimate` , annotated by 4 in the table 12-17  :

```
est_ope=VarCorr(fit)$operator[1]
est_part = VarCorr(fit)$part[1]
sig = summary(fit)$sigma
est_res = sig^2
```

Now I want to extract the results of `Std Errors` , annotated by 5 in the table 12-17 from  lmer output .

Many Thanks !

Comment: can you post the data for this example?  It would also help to know what you're going to use the standard errors for (as I point out below, standard errors of variance estimates are unreliable uncertainty metrics -- profile intervals will be better)

Comment: Why do you want standard errors for a parameter that is not symmetrically distributed. You should reframe the question you ask. Don't imitate the SAS mistake. If you want hypo test then use anove function. If you want CI, use profile or bootstrap CI. There are reasons why lmer does not give the number you ask for. Although Ben tells you how you might get it. Don't let fact that SAS or Stata report that influence you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Wald standard error of the variance estimates. Please note that these (as often pointed out by Doug Bates) the Wald standard errors are often **very poor** estimates of the uncertainty of variances, because the likelihood profiles are often far from quadratic on the variance scale ... I'm assuming you know what you're doing and have some good use for these numbers ...

This can be (now) done using the `merDeriv` package.

```r
library(lme4)
library(merDeriv)
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
sqrt(diag(vcov(m1, full = TRUE)))
vv <- vcov(m1, full = TRUE)
colnames(vv)
## [1] "(Intercept)"                  "Days"                        
## [3] "cov_Subject.(Intercept)"      "cov_Subject.Days.(Intercept)"
## [5] "cov_Subject.Days"             "residual"
```

Because this represents the full/combined covariance matrix, the first two indices (rows/columns) {(Intercept), Days} represent the fixed-effect intercept and slope. The elements prefaced by `cov_` are variance components, in the format `cov_<grp_variable>.<term>` for variances (e.g. `cov_Subject.(Intercept)` is the among-subject variance in the intercept) and `cov_<grp_variable>.<term1>.<term2>` for covariances (`cov_Subject.Days.(Intercept)` is the among-subject covariance between the slope (`Days`) and the intercept). `residual` denotes the residual variance.

If we want the standard errors of the variance components, we take the square root of the diagonal and keep only elements 3 to 5:

```r
sqrt(diag(vv)[3:5])
## [1] 288.78602  46.67876  14.78208
```

or more generally

```r
sqrt(diag(vv)[grepl("^cov", colnames(vv))])
```

(weirdly, only `colnames()` works — the row names of `vv` are blank for the random effects components).

### old answer

```
library("lme4")
model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), sleepstudy, REML=FALSE)
```

(At present it's quite a bit harder to do this for the REML estimates ...)

Extract deviance function parameterized in terms of standard deviation and correlation rather than in terms of Cholesky factors (note this an internal function, so there's not a guarantee that it will keep working in the same way in the future ...)

```
 dd.ML <- lme4:::devfun2(model,useSc=TRUE,signames=FALSE)
```

Extract parameters as standard deviations on original scale:

```
 vv <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(model)) ## need ML estimates!
 pars <- vv[,"sdcor"]
 ## will need to be careful about order if using this for
 ## a random-slopes model ...
```

Now compute the second-derivative (Hessian) matrix:

```
library("numDeriv")
hh1 <- hessian(dd.ML,pars)
vv2 <- 2*solve(hh1)  ## 2* converts from log-likelihood to deviance scale
sqrt(diag(vv2))  ## get standard errors
```

These are the standard errors of the standard deviations: double them to get the standard errors of the variances (when you transform a value, its standard errors scale according to the derivative of the transformation).

I think this should do it, but you might want to double-check it ...

Comment: Could you please give me a reference for REML estimate . The result in the table is for standard error of  REML estimates of variance component . Perhaps thats why I don't get the answer . I have correctly specified the model and also get the REML estimates of variance component by `VarCorr(model)` which matches with the result in the table . Would be really helpful if you refer me how to compute standard errors of the standard deviations of `lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days||Subject), sleepstudy)`

Comment: Is it possible in lmer to calculate the standard error of the standard deviation of REML estimates ?

Comment: If I write `REML=TRUE` and proceed in same manner , won't it work?

Comment: I think probably not. I might open an issue at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues ... There are a couple of ways to do this, but no very simple solutions.

Comment: @BenBolker, I am actually confused by the column names of the output of `merDeriv:: vcov`. If I denote the random effects as $\sigma_{subject}$, $\sigma_{days}$ and their covariance $\sigma_{01}$ and want to find out $SE(\sigma_{subject})$, $SE(\sigma_{days})$ and $SE(\sigma_{01})$. Would you kindly clarify which one which among `"cov_Subject.(Intercept)"`,   `"cov_Subject.Days.(Intercept)"`, and `"cov_Subject.Days"`?. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "standard error of variance component". My best guess (based on your code) is that you want the standard error of the random effect. You can get this using package arm:

```
library(arm)
se.ranef(model)
#$Subject
#    (Intercept)
#308    9.475668
#309    9.475668
#310    9.475668
#330    9.475668
#331    9.475668
#332    9.475668
#333    9.475668
#334    9.475668
#335    9.475668
#337    9.475668
#349    9.475668
#350    9.475668
#351    9.475668
#352    9.475668
#369    9.475668
#370    9.475668
#371    9.475668
#372    9.475668
```

This is actually the square root of the conditional variance-covariance matrix of the random effect:

```
sqrt(attr(ranef(model, condVar = TRUE)$Subject, "postVar"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mn2=lmer(pun~ pre + (pre|pro), REML = TRUE, data = pro)
summary(mn2)
coe2=coef(mn2)
coe2

# Matriz de varianza-covarianza (covarianza)
as.data.frame(VarCorr(mn2))

# Extraer coeficientes fijos
fixef(mn2)

# Extraer desvios de a - alfa y b - beta
re=as.data.frame(ranef(mn2))
```

Comment: Asking as.data.frame to the random effects option (ranef) converts to long format condsd correspond with conditional standard deviation