# Two-level modelling with lme in R

Tags: r, m

I am interested in estimating a mixed effect model with two random components (I am sorry for the somewhat unprecise notation. I am somewhat new to these kind of models). Finally, I also want also the standard errors of the variances of the random components. That is why I am somewhat boudn to using the package `lme`. The reason is that I found this description on how to calculate those standard errors and also interesting, the standard error for function of these variances [link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-calculate-standard-errors-for-variance-components-from-mixed-models/).

I believe I know how to use the package `lmer`. I am finally interested in `model2`. For the `model1`, both command yield the same estimates. But `model2` with `lme` yields different results than `model2` with `lmer` from the `lme4` package. Could you help me to get around how to set up the random components for `lme`? This would be much appreciated. Thanks. Please find attached my MWE.

Best

Daniel

```
#### load all packages #####

loadpackage <- function(x){
  for( i in x ){
    #  require returns TRUE invisibly if it was able to load package
    if( ! require( i , character.only = TRUE ) ){
      #  If package was not able to be loaded then re-install
      install.packages( i , dependencies = TRUE )
    }
    #  Load package (after installing)
    library( i , character.only = TRUE )
  }
}

#  Then try/install packages...

loadpackage( c("nlme", "msm", "lmeInfo", "lme4"))
alcohol1 <- read.table("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/alda/data/alcohol1_pp.txt", header=T, sep=",")
attach(alcohol1)

id <- as.factor(id)
age <- as.factor(age)


model1.lmer <-lmer(alcuse ~ 1  + peer + (1|id))
summary(model1.lmer)
model2.lmer <-lmer(alcuse ~ 1  + peer + (1|id) + (1|age))
summary(model2.lmer)

model1.lme <- lme(alcuse ~ 1+ peer, data = alcohol1, random = ~ 1 |id, method ="REML")
summary(model1.lme)
model2.lme <- lme(alcuse ~ 1+ peer, data = alcohol1, random = ~ 1 |id + 1|age, method ="REML")
```

Edit (15/09/2021):

Estimating the model as follows end then returning the estimates via `nlme::VarCorr` gives me different results. While the estimates seem to be in the ball park, it is as they are switched across components.

```
model2a.lme <- lme(alcuse ~ 1+ peer, data = alcohol1, random = ~ 1 |id/age, method ="REML")
summary(model2a.lme)

nlme::VarCorr(model2a.lme)
            Variance     StdDev   
id =        pdLogChol(1)          
(Intercept) 0.38390274   0.6195989
age =       pdLogChol(1)          
(Intercept) 0.47892113   0.6920413
Residual    0.08282585   0.2877948
```

EDIT (16/09/2021):

Since Bob pushed me to think more about my model, I want to give some additional information. Please know that the data I use in the MWE do not match my true data. I just used it for illustrative purposes since I can not upload myy true data. I have a household panel with income, demographic informations and parent indicators.

I am interested in intergenerational mobility. Sibling correlations of permanent income are one industry standard. At the very least, contemporanous observations are very bad proxies of permanent income. Due to transitory shocks, i.e., classical measurement error, those estimates are most certainly attenuated. For this reason, we exploit the longitudinal dimension of our data.

For sibling correlations, this amounts to hypothesising that the income process is as follows:

$$Y_{ijt} = \beta X_{ijt} + \epsilon_{ijt}.$$

With Y being income from individual i from family j in year t. X comprises age and survey year indicators to account for life-cycle effects and macroeconmic conditions in survey years. Epsilon is a compund term comprising a random individual and family component as well as a transitory component (measurement error and short lived shocks). It looks as follows:

$$\epsilon_{ijt} = \alpha_i + \gamma_j + \eta_{ijt}.$$

The variance of income is then:

$$\sigma^2_\epsilon = \sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2\gamma + \sigma^2\eta.$$

The quantitiy we are interested in is

$$\rho = \frac(\sigma^2\gamma}{\sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2\gamma},$$

which reflects the share of shared family (and other characteristics) among siblings of the variation in permanent income.

B.t.w.: The struggle is simply because I want to have a standard errors for all estimates and for \rho.

Comment: I think you should post your answer as an **answer** rather than editing your question ... you are welcome to switch your "accepted" checkmark from my answer to your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally. Just to sketch my confidential data: I have a panel of individuals. The data includes siblings, identified via mnr. income is earnings, wavey survey year, age age factors. female a factor for gender, pid is the factor identifying the individual.

```
m1 <- lmer(income ~ age + wavey + female + (1|pid) + (1 | mnr),
        data = panel)
vv <- vcov(m1, full = TRUE)

covvar <- vv[58:60, 58:60]
covvar
3 x 3 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     cov_pid.(Intercept) cov_mnr.(Intercept)   residual
[1,]           2.6528679          -1.4624588 -0.4077576
[2,]          -1.4624588           3.1015001 -0.0597926
[3,]          -0.4077576          -0.0597926  1.1634680

mean <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(m1))$vcov
mean
[1] 17.92341 16.86084 56.77185
deltamethod(~ x2/(x1+x2), mean, covvar, ses =TRUE)
[1] 0.04242089
```

The last scalar should be what I interprete as the shared background of the siblings of permanent income.

Thanks to @Ben Bolker who pointed me into this direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of *crossed* vs *nested* random effects. (Note that the example you refer to is fitting a different kind of model, a *random-slopes* model rather than a model with two different grouping variables ...)

If you try `with(alcohol1, table(age,id))` you can see that every `id` is associated with every possible age (14, 15, 16). Or `subset(alcohol1, id==1)` for example:

```r
  id age coa male age_14   alcuse     peer     cpeer  ccoa
1  1  14   1    0      0 1.732051 1.264911 0.2469111 0.549
2  1  15   1    0      1 2.000000 1.264911 0.2469111 0.549
3  1  16   1    0      2 2.000000 1.264911 0.2469111 0.549
```

There are three possible models you could fit for a model with random effects of `age`(indexed by `i`) and `id` (indexed by `j`)

- **crossed** (`(1|age) + (1|id)`): `Y_{ij} = beta0 + beta1*peer + eps1_i + eps2_j +epsr_{ij}`; alcohol use varies among individuals and, independently, across ages (this model won't work very well because there are only three distinct ages in the data set, more levels are usually needed)
- **id nested within age** (`(1|age/id)` = `(1|age) + (1|age:id)`): 
  `Y_{ij} = beta0 + beta1*peer + eps1_i + eps2_{ij} + epsr_{ij}`; alcohol use varies across ages, and varies across individuals within ages (see note above about number of levels).
- **age nested within id** (`(1|id/age)` = `(1|id) + (1|age:id)`): 
  `Y_{ij} = beta0 + beta1*peer + eps1_j + eps2_{ij} + epsr_{ij}`; alcohol use varies across individuals, and varies across ages within individuals

Here `eps1_i`, `eps2_{ij}`, and `epsr_{ij}` are normal deviates; `epsr` is the residual error term.

The latter two models actually don't make sense in this case; because there is only one observation per age/id combination, the nested variance (`eps2`) is completely confounded with the residual variance (`epsr`). `lme` doesn't notice this; if you try to fit one of the nested models in `lmer` it will give an error that

> number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: id:age)

(Although if you try to compute confidence intervals based on `model1.lme` you'll get an error "cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components: Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance", which is a hint that something is wrong.)

You could restate this problem as saying that the residual variation, and the variation among ages within individuals, are *jointly unidentifiable* (can't be separated from each other, statistically).

The **updated** answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694812/standard-error-of-variance-component-from-the-output-of-lmer) shows how to get the standard errors of the variance components from an `lmer` model, so you shouldn't be stuck with `lme` (but you *should* think carefully about which model you're really trying to fit ...)

The [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed) might also be useful.

More generally, the standard error of

```
rho = (V_gamma)/(V_alpha + V_gamma)
```

will be hard to compute accurately, because this is a *nonlinear* function of the model parameters.  You can apply the *delta method*, but the most reliable approach would be to use *parametric bootstrapping*: if you have a fitted model `m`, then something like this should work:

```r
var_ratio <- function(m) {
   v <- as.data.frame(sapply(VarCorr(m), as.numeric))
   return(v$family/(v$family + v$id))
}
confint(m, method="boot", FUN =var_ratio)
```

Comment: Dear @Ben, thanks for your input. Indeed, I already came across you other contribution in the linked thread. I think I am just one step away from implementing the crossed design. I will be giving more information in the original thread above. At the moment, I can not get `model2b.lme <- lme(alcuse ~ 1 + peer, data = alcohol1, random = ~  (1|age) + (1|id), method ="REML")` running. I believe it is just one more minor step.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's just one more minor step.  Crossed random effects are hard to implement in `lme` . I tried to follow the example linked to in the GLMM FAQ from Pinheiro and Bates, i.e. `model4.lme <- lme(alcuse ~ 1 + peer, data=alcohol1, random = pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~age-1), pdIdent(~id-1))))`, but couldn't make it work and gave up. (Why not use `lmer` ?)

Comment: Already at it. I started with `lme` because UCLA (link in intital question) provided such a nice documentation on how to achive what I want. But I understand that I can achieve everything with what you provided in the linked thread. I might come back as soon as possible with a solution (hopefully).

Comment: Dear @BenBolker, I finally found what I want. It's basically the delta method applied to what you provide in your linked thread. I hope this works out. My machine just needs a while to return the vcov due to the the large number of FEs. Thanks! Hints how to edit the title to be informative for future truth seeking R coders will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify random effects in `lme` by using `/` not `+`

## By `lmer`

```
model2.lmer <-lmer(alcuse ~ 1  + peer + (1|id) + (1|age), data = alcohol1)
summary(model2.lmer)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: alcuse ~ 1 + peer + (1 | id) + (1 | age)
   Data: alcohol1

REML criterion at convergence: 651.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0228 -0.5310 -0.1329  0.5854  3.1545 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.08078  0.2842  
 age      (Intercept) 0.30313  0.5506  
 Residual             0.56175  0.7495  
Number of obs: 246, groups:  id, 82; age, 82

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   0.3039     0.1438   2.113
peer          0.6074     0.1151   5.276

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
peer -0.814
```

## By `lme`

```
model2.lme <- lme(alcuse ~ 1+ peer, data = alcohol1, random = ~ 1 |id/age, method ="REML")
summary(model2.lme)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: alcohol1 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  661.3109 678.7967 -325.6554

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | id
        (Intercept)
StdDev:   0.4381206

 Formula: ~1 | age %in% id
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.4381203 0.7494988

Fixed effects: alcuse ~ 1 + peer 
                Value Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.3038946 0.1438333 164 2.112825  0.0361
peer        0.6073948 0.1151228  80 5.276060  0.0000
 Correlation: 
     (Intr)
peer -0.814

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.0227793 -0.5309669 -0.1329302  0.5853768  3.1544873 

Number of Observations: 246
Number of Groups: 
         id age %in% id 
         82          82
```

Comment: Dear @Park, thanks for the kind reply. Maybe I am missinterpreting your response. But I was interested in the variance of both of the randomcomponents. However, the output of the lme model does not provide those. In addition, at first glance, I can not recover those two variances from the lme results.

Comment: @Daniel2805 Try `nlme::VarCorr`

Comment: Dear @Park: I While I see where this is heading too, The results seem not to match those from `lme4::lmer`. You can see more details in my edit.