# Standard Error of Random Effects in case of glmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I am aware of the reason why the output of `lmer`/`glmer` does not provide the SE of random effects, but still, I do need them. In search of ways to achieve them, I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31704646/10858321)  on SO that shows two ways,

- One is using the `{merDeriv}` R package. Unfortunately, this package does not work for three-level intercept model.
- Another one is using the `lme4:::devfun2` function, which also does not work for the `glmer` case.

I have found [another article](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/28864_dd1f084207d54f5ea67c9d1a9c845d01.html) which provides a generalized function based on `devfun2` that does run for `glmer` too. But I am skeptical about the output.

### Reprex

```r
# copied from
# http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/28864_dd1f084207d54f5ea67c9d1a9c845d01.html
vcov.VarCorr.merMod <- function(object,fit,...) {
  if (isREML(fit)) {
    warning("refitting model with ML")
    fit <- refitML(fit)
  }
  if (!require("numDeriv")) stop("numDeriv package required")
  useSc <- attr(object,"useSc")
  dd <- lme4:::devfun2(fit,useSc=useSc,signames=FALSE)
  vdd <- as.data.frame(object,order="lower.tri")
  pars <- vdd[,"sdcor"]
  npar0 <- length(pars)
  if (isGLMM(fit)) {
    pars <- c(pars,fixef(fit))
  }
  hh1 <- hessian(dd,pars)
  vv2 <- 2*solve(hh1)
  if (isGLMM(fit)) {
    vv2 <- vv2[1:npar0,1:npar0,drop=FALSE]
  }
  nms <- apply(vdd[,1:3],1,
               function(x) paste(na.omit(x),collapse="."))
  dimnames(vv2) <- list(nms,nms)
  return(vv2)
}
```

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

l = 20 # for level 3
m = 10 # for level 2
n = 15 # for level 1
N = l*m*n 

set.seed(344920)

x1c <- rnorm(N)
x2 <- rnorm(N)
x2b <- ifelse(x2 <= 0.5, 0, 1)

sigma_u_sq <- 2
sigma_v_sq <- 2.5

beta0 <- -1.85
beta1 <- 1.75
beta2 <- 0.67

ujk <- rep(rnorm(l*m, 0, sqrt(sigma_u_sq)), each = n)
vk <- rep(rnorm(l, 0, sqrt(sigma_v_sq)), each = m*n)

eta_ijk <- beta0 + beta1*x1c + beta2*x2b + ujk + vk
pi_ijk <- exp(eta_ijk) / (1 + exp(eta_ijk))
yijk <- rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = pi_ijk)

multi_data_int <- data.frame(
  ea = rep(seq(l), each = m*n),
  hh = rep(rep(seq(m), each = n), times = l),
  id = rep(seq(n), times = l*m),
  ujk = ujk,
  vk = vk,
  X1c = x1c,
  X2b = x2b,
  Yijk = yijk
)

head(multi_data_int, 20)
#>    ea hh id        ujk        vk          X1c X2b Yijk
#> 1   1  1  1 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.007794036   0    0
#> 2   1  1  2 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.234132332   1    1
#> 3   1  1  3 2.90637424 -1.445273 -1.889608999   1    0
#> 4   1  1  4 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.422145090   0    0
#> 5   1  1  5 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.419108964   0    0
#> 6   1  1  6 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.888562337   0    0
#> 7   1  1  7 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.225015650   1    0
#> 8   1  1  8 2.90637424 -1.445273  0.975207945   0    1
#> 9   1  1  9 2.90637424 -1.445273  0.758737508   1    1
#> 10  1  1 10 2.90637424 -1.445273  0.076975064   0    0
#> 11  1  1 11 2.90637424 -1.445273 -1.365477668   0    0
#> 12  1  1 12 2.90637424 -1.445273  2.321368515   0    1
#> 13  1  1 13 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.193308257   1    1
#> 14  1  1 14 2.90637424 -1.445273 -0.176744295   1    0
#> 15  1  1 15 2.90637424 -1.445273  0.008025087   0    0
#> 16  1  2  1 0.09326023 -1.445273 -0.402981705   0    0
#> 17  1  2  2 0.09326023 -1.445273 -0.558394540   0    0
#> 18  1  2  3 0.09326023 -1.445273  2.184687818   1    1
#> 19  1  2  4 0.09326023 -1.445273  0.852252381   0    0
#> 20  1  2  5 0.09326023 -1.445273  0.454781476   0    0

model <- glmer(Yijk ~ X1c + X2b + (1 | ea) + (1 | ea:hh),
               data = multi_data_int, family = "binomial")


vcov(VarCorr(model), model)
#> Loading required package: numDeriv
#>                   ea:hh.(Intercept) ea.(Intercept)
#> ea:hh.(Intercept)       -0.07344817     -0.1000162
#> ea.(Intercept)          -0.10001619     -0.1432521
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, it is giving the SE in negative values. **Is this function `vcov.VarCorr.merMod` giving the correct values or it is giving the standard error in the log-cholesky scale? if so, can anybody help me to get the values in the usual scale?**

Comment: If you need help calculating values from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. It requires more knowledge about statistics than the R programming language.